# Alternate method to avoid loop in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, loops, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
table2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Product Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'State_1_Value': [10, 11, 12, 13],
    'State_2_Value': [20, 21, 22, 23],
    'State_3_Value': [30, 31, 32, 33],
    'State_4_Value': [40, 41, 42, 43],
    'State_5_Value': [50, 51, 52, 53],
    'State_6_Value': [60, 61, 62, 63],
    'Lower_Bound': [-1, 1, .5, 5],
    'Upper_Bound': [1, 2, .625, 15],
    'sim_1': [0, 0, .61, 7],
    'sim_2': [1, 1.5, .7, 9],
    })

>>> table2
   Lower_Bound Product Type  State_1_Value  State_2_Value  State_3_Value  \
0         -1.0            A             10             20             30   
1          1.0            B             11             21             31   
2          0.5            C             12             22             32   
3          5.0            D             13             23             33   

   State_4_Value  State_5_Value  State_6_Value  Upper_Bound  sim_1  sim_2  
0             40             50             60        1.000    0.0    1.0  
1             41             51             61        2.000    0.0    1.5  
2             42             52             62        0.625    0.61    0.7  
3             43             53             63       15.000    7.0    9.0
```

And I wrote the following code to generate a new DataFrame with a modified output for each 'sim'

```
for i in range(1,3):
    table2['Bucket%s'%i] = 5 * (table2['sim_%s'%i] - table2['Lower_Bound']) / (table2['Upper_Bound'] - table2['Lower_Bound']) + 1
    table2['lv'] = table2['Bucket%s'%i].map(int)
    table2['hv'] = table2['Bucket%s'%i].map(int) + 1
    table2.ix[table2['lv'] < 1 , 'lv'] = 1
    table2.ix[table2['lv'] > 5 , 'lv'] = 5
    table2.ix[table2['hv'] > 6 , 'hv'] = 6
    table2.ix[table2['hv'] < 2 , 'hv'] = 2
    table2['nLower'] = table2.apply(lambda row: row['State_%s_Value'%row['lv']],axis=1)
    table2['nHigher'] = table2.apply(lambda row: row['State_%s_Value'%row['hv']],axis=1)
    table2['Final_value_%s'%i] = (table2['nHigher'] - table2['nLower'])*(table2['Bucket%s'%i]-table2['lv']) + table2['nLower']
df = table2.filter(regex="sim|Type")
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Product Type  sim_1  sim_2
0            A   35.0   60.0
1            B  -39.0   36.0
2            C   56.0   92.0
3            D   23.0   33.0
```

I want to run this on 10,000 sims, and currently each loop takes about .25 seconds. Is there any way to modify this code to avoid the loop and be more time efficient?

Edit: If you're curious what this code is trying to accomplish you can see my self-answered somewhat disorganized question here: [Pandas DataFrame: Complex linear interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662113/pandas-dataframe-complex-linear-interpolation)

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want the code to do (desired input -> desired output)? Right now, in order to help you, someone would have to invest the effort to understand why you wrote your current code.

Comment: Hi Sweater-Baron, I added a link to the bottom of the question which shows what my code is accomplishing.

Comment: I was able to change the first line of the code where we make the bucket to not require a loop: df.ix[:,-2:] = df.ix[:,-2:].sub(df['Lower_Bound'],axis=0).div(df['Upper_Bound'].sub(df['Lower_Bound'],axis=0),axis=0) * 5 + 1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with no loops using the following code:

As a result on my 10k x 200 table it ran in 3 minutes instead of the previous 2 hours.

Unfortunately now I need to run it on a 10k x 4k table, and I hit MemoryError on that one, but it may be out of the scope of this question.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
            'Product Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
            'State_1_Value': [10, 11, 12, 13],
        'State_2_Value': [20, 21, 22, 23],
        'State_3_Value': [30, 31, 32, 33],
        'State_4_Value': [40, 41, 42, 43],
        'State_5_Value': [50, 51, 52, 53],
        'State_6_Value': [60, 61, 62, 63],
        'Lower_Bound': [-1, 1, .5, 5],
        'Upper_Bound': [1, 2, .625, 15],
        'sim_1': [0, 0, .61, 7],
        'sim_2': [1, 1.5, .7, 9],
        })


buckets = df.ix[:,-2:].sub(df['Lower_Bound'],axis=0).div(df['Upper_Bound'].sub(df['Lower_Bound'],axis=0),axis=0) * 5 + 1
low = buckets.applymap(int)
high = buckets.applymap(int) + 1
low = low.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x < 1 else x)
low = low.applymap(lambda x: 5 if x > 5 else x)
high = high.applymap(lambda x: 6 if x > 6 else x)
high = high.applymap(lambda x: 2 if x < 2 else x)
low_value = pd.DataFrame(df.filter(regex="State|Type").values[np.arange(low.shape[0])[:,None], low])
high_value = pd.DataFrame(df.filter(regex="State|Type").values[np.arange(high.shape[0])[:,None], high])
df1 = (high_value - low_value).mul((buckets - low).values) + low_value
df1['Product Type'] = df['Product Type']
```